# the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<char>` is not implemented for `&str`

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

```
let mut map: HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();

for (i, c) in text.chars().enumerate() {
    if map.contains_key(&c) {
    // Do something
    }
}
```

the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<char>` is not implemented for `&str`

I need an explanation of this error and how to fix it please. I am looping through every character in a text and inserting the ones not already in a hashmap into the hash map. But i keep getting the error as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chars` is an `Iterator`, whose `Item = char`, so your `HashMap<&str, u32>` is not compatible with it.

`&str` is a string slice (essentialy a sequence of characters), while a `char` is a single character.

You must decide:

- Should `map` really map from `&str` to `u32`? Or possibly from `char`? Or possibly from `&char`?
- If you go for `&str`, you must convert `chars`'s elements to `&str`.